# How to implement tap on focus in react natie using expo camera?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, autofocus, expo-camera

I am using [expo camera](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#focusdepth) and I have wrapped it inside `TapGestureHandler` so I can detect tap event. Here is the code:

```
<TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={onSingleTapEvent}>
  <View>
    <Camera
      ref={cameraRef}
      type={cameraType}
      ratio={ratio}
      onCameraReady={onCameraReady}
      autoFocus={Camera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}
    ></Camera>
  </View>
</TapGestureHandler>;
```

My `onSingleTapEvent`:

```
 const onSingleTapEvent = (event) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
      console.log("Single tap event: ", event.nativeEvent);
    }
  };
```

When I tap on the screen I see the following console output:

```
    Single tap event:  Object {
  "absoluteX": 210.3333282470703,
  "absoluteY": 527.3333129882812,
  "handlerTag": 3,
  "numberOfPointers": 1,
  "oldState": 2,
  "state": 4,
  "x": 210.3333282470703,
  "y": 446.3333435058594,
}
```

My question is, how do I implement tap on focus? As far as I understand I need to play with `focusDepth` [property](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#focusdepth) of expo camera, but I don't know how to set it? Any ideas, bogs or pseudo code would be grant!

Comment: https://forums.expo.io/t/camera-tap-to-focus-or-using-non-expo-components-with-expo/6232 There is a feature request for this: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/camera-focus-at-point-on-touch

Comment: @M.Kotzjan I know about this request but I was hoping to implement it myself as I dont want to wait

Comment: I don't think focusDepth is the way to got for you since you would need the distance to the object, not the coordinates of the tap. How about opening the default camera app with `Expo.ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync`?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a nice way to do this by resetting the autofocus on user tap event and it works really well.

```
export default function CameraScreen({ route, navigation }: any) {
    const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);
    const [focusSquare, setFocusSquare] = useState({ visible: false, x: 0, y: 0 });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isRefreshing) {
            setIsRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, [isRefreshing]);

    // Function to handle touch events
    const handleTouch = (event: any) => {
        const { locationX, locationY } = event.nativeEvent;
        setFocusSquare({ visible: true, x: locationX, y: locationY });

        // Hide the square after 1 second
        setTimeout(() => {
            setFocusSquare((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, visible: false }));
        }, 1000);

        setIsRefreshing(true);
    };

    return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <PinchGestureHandler
          onGestureEvent={handlePinch}
          onHandlerStateChange={(event) => {
            if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.END) {
              const scale = event.nativeEvent.scale;
              setZoom((currentZoom) => scale * currentZoom);
            }
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Camera
              style={styles.camera}
              type={type}
              ref={camera}
              zoom={zoom}
              autoFocus={!isRefreshing ? AutoFocus.on : AutoFocus.off}
              onTouchEnd={handleTouch} // Handle touch to set focus point
            >
            </Camera>

            {focusSquare.visible && (
              <View
                style={[
                  styles.focusSquare,
                  { top: focusSquare.y - 25, left: focusSquare.x - 25 },
                ]}
              />
            )}

          </View>
        </PinchGestureHandler>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    camera: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    focusSquare: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).